# HTML Pattern for phone numbers

Tags: html, regex

This is my first time writing a pattern for HTML phone numbers. I am based in Singapore. In my country phone numbers starts with 8 or 9 and has 9 digits.

This is my html pattern.

Can someone take look and let me know what went wrong?

I don't see any resources out there for including certain numbers only.

pattern: ([8|9]{1}[0-9]{8})

below is my full code

```
 <h3>Sign Up</h3>
                        <label htmlFor="username" className="sr-only">Username: </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="username"
                            minLength= '5'
                            maxLength= '10' 
                            onChange={onChange}
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Enter Username" required />
                        <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">Password: </label>
                        <input type="password"
                            name="password"
                            minLength= '8'
                            pattern = "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"
                            title = "Must contain at least one  number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Enter Password" />
                        <label htmlFor="email" className="sr-only">Email: </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            name="email"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"
                            className="form-control"
                            placeholder="Email" required />
                        <label htmlFor="mobile" className="sr-only">Mobile Number: </label>
                        <input type="number"
                            name="mobile"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            className="form-control"
                            pattern="[8-9]{1}[0-9]{8}"
                            placeholder="Mobile Number" />
                        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                            type="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the regex you've posted?  What doesn't work?

Comment: it does do anything when I enter the contact number in the form

Comment: Let's have a look at more of your code

Comment: sure i have added my full code. thank you!

Comment: If you're using react or some sort of JS library, please update your tags.

Comment: The pipe character inside []'s doesn't mean "or".  I believe you are looking for `([89][0-9]{8})`

Comment: Pretty sure "pattern" isn't a valid attribute on input's with type=number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that `pattern` is not a valid attribute on input when type=number. Also the pipe character inside []'s doesn't mean "or". Either change the input type to another value, or use min/max.

```
 <input type="text" inputmode="numeric"
   name="mobile"
   onChange={onChange}
   className="form-control"
   pattern="[89][0-9]{8}"
   placeholder="Mobile Number" />
```

or

```
 <input type="number"
   name="mobile"
   onChange={onChange}
   className="form-control"
   min=800000000
   max=999999999
   step=1
   placeholder="Mobile Number" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I was learning about patterns today. Didn't know pattern dont work with types.

Comment: I would also like to ask in what circumstances is pipe used for. I was under the impression it is a form of "or"

Comment: The pipe is used as an "or" for different patterns, like (abc|def), but for character restrictions, you already just list the characters, so a pipe would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect that using `pattern` on input will prevent you from entering incorrect data base on that pattern, you're wrong.

You have to submit the form for the browser to validate. The first form bellow will submit, the second one will not.

```html
<form>
  <input value="891234567" type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="([89][0-9]{8})" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<form>
  <input value="121234567" type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="([89][0-9]{8})" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Edit:**
As @Robert McKee pointed in the comment below, the first pattern used on this answer is incorrect. Updated `pattern` to `([89][0-9]{8})`.

Comment: Change the first character to a | and it'll submit.

Comment: Try `|91234567`, and it will.

Comment: Ohh.. I see. I updated my answer to use the pattern I saw from one of your comments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Phone number starting with 8-9 and remaing 9 digit with 0-9" required

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="" name="enquiry_mobile" placeholder="Enter mobile number *" pattern="[8-9]{1}[0-9]{8}">
```